# Is there a workaround for random xcode segue actions?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a strange situation.  Have searched high and low but found nothing for others experiencing the same.

In my app there is a table view controller with multiple cells.  Each cell does a push segue to a different view controller.  When run, most work fine, but a few begin the segue (I see the text on the view controller beginning to slide in) but then the scene goes blank.  The navigation is present and lets me unwind back to the table view controller.

The strange thing is that when I rebuild and rerun it's different segues that act that way and the ones that were previously acting funny are now correct.  I thought this might be an issue in the simulator but the app I put on the App Store is doing the same thing.

Is this a known bug in XCODE and does anyone know of a workaround?

I am running XCODE V5.1.1 under OS X V10.9.3.

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine it's a bug in URcode, not Xcode.  Doing anything silly like storing variables at global-scope?

Comment: Is it possible to add a cut down code sample that exhibits the bug? It's kind of hard to help with this little info.

Comment: As above, please post some example code so we can take a look at exactly what you're doing.

Comment: No code to show.  Just using storyboard to CTRL drag from a table view cell to a view controller.  BTW, same thing happens with modal segue.